# JS Замыкания и цикл с таймаутом.

Tags: javascript, замыкания

Всеми любимый цикл.

```
function f(){
    for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            console.log(i);
        }, 1000);
    }
}
```

Выводит десять десяток. Предполагаю, что цикл выполнится раньше, чем запустится анон функция. 
Но.
Почему так случается, если цикл не переходит дальше (то есть плюсует i, делает проверку на истинность и т.д до i=10) пока не выполниться setТimeout(...)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Почитайте, как работает setTimeout, но до этого, что такое замыкание, а то сейчас получится [так](http://habrastorage.org/files/ce4/3ea/8df/ce43ea8dfd534e0caab2ec8fa05a108b.jpeg).